# Byte Array to Bitmap Image android

Tags: android, arrays, android-imageview, bitmapimage

I'm trying to set an image from byte to a bitmap and set it to a imageView, but i'm getting a null pointer exception whenever i set it to a imageView, Sorry for a noob question i'm just new with the byte and bitmaps

Here's the code:

```
iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                      if (e == null) {
                        // use data for something
                        Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
                        Log.d("test", " "+bmp.toString());
                        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp); <----- here getting error
                      } else {
                        Log.d("test", "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                      }
                    }
                  });
```

iv is declared locally in the class.
Thanks in advance for helping.

Here is my logcat as requested:

```
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.shop.browser.ItemInfoActivity$1$1.done(ItemInfoActivity.java:115)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.parse.ParseFile$2.done(ParseFile.java:396)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.parse.GetDataCallback.internalDone(GetDataCallback.java:21)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.parse.GetDataCallback.internalDone(GetDataCallback.java:1)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.parse.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:50)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.parse.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:1)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-06 20:15:46.417: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please provide your logcat

Comment: seems iv is null here. Please check whether u cast the rigth id.. provide logcat data as well

Comment: it's acceptable to call `setImageBitmap` with `null` argument so in your case `iv` is actually `null`. make sure that you have an `ImageView` with id `R.id.imageView1` in your layout.

Comment: Guys can you post your comment as an answer below so i can accept it. I'm just stupid i set the wrong id

Comment: @user1708134 no need, post your answer and accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Bitmap bmp = intent.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

> 1. before use this above code check your byteArray size if they have then decode image like this way.
> 2. And one thing also remember UI is not possible to change in thread background

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray , 0, byteArray .length);
 iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap );
```